# NetSuite - Customer Deposit Negative Balance

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

It seems we cannot enter a negative amount when we want to create a customer deposit record. We have customers who are in overdraft so we need a way to capture negative amount.

How would we do this? We need a way of monitoring billable customer account balance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might be best to generate a cashsale with an item (service) you set up for overdraft.   The amount the customer is in overdraft would be the rate/amount.

You need to show that the customer has a negotiate balance.  The only way to really do that correctly is to create a billable transaction, such as salesorder, invoice, or cashsale.